# Creating object of a class using index

Tags: c++, oop

I have classes like this:
Class1
Class2
Class3
Class4
Class5
Class6
...
...
...
ClassN

In one of the function I need to create an object of the class based on the input parameter of the function.

For example, if the input is 1 then I need to create an object for Class1, if 2 then Class2 object.

Is it possible to create an object without using if condition? I dont want if condition for all the classes.

Comment: Something sounds terribly wrong if you have classes called `Class1` ... `ClassN`. How similar are these classes? Can you show us what they're like and what differs between them?

Comment: Looks to me like you fight with C++ instead of using it. Having Class1...ClassN is a signal. Tell us more about the problem you try to solve and maybe someone will suggest a solution more in C++ spirit.

Comment: Joining the others with the request to shade some more light on what is your design guideline - we might offer something else. specifically to your question, i don't think you can avoid the if condition to create different types from run time user input

Comment: Do all of your classes share a common parent class?  How are you planning on managing the resulting object?

Comment: I have a base class(abstract) and has one pure virtual function. I have around 40 derived classes which implement the virtual function. Virtual function will print the tables(totally 40 tables). I will create the derived class object based on the table number which is an input. currently I have 40 IF conditions to check the input and create derived class object. So is there any way to get rid of all IF conditions and use single line to create an derived class object based on input number??

Comment: You need a factory and a vector or map of pointers to function.

Comment: @dohashi: Yes I have a common parent class which has one pure virtual function.

Comment: The only way I know of avoiding if conditions is to use a factory function and to overload it. Maybe if your tables have different types...

Comment: @impulse We're suggesting that there must be something wrong with your program architecture for you to have this problem in the first place. There is not a single time I would ever have a bunch of classes that have enumerated names. Never ever. And unfortunately, I can't really tell from your previous description why your architecture is like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use inheritance, you need a factory function to spawn any derived type ...

```
template<typename T>
base * spawn ()
{
    return new T();
}
```

... and a container that support random access with `operator[]`.

Choose a map if you need indexes that are not contiguous :

```
std::map<int, base *(*)()> map_spawner =
{
    { 0, &spawn<child_1> },
    { 1, &spawn<child_2> }
};
```

Choose a vector if indexes are contiguous :

```
std::vector<base *(*)()> vec_spawner =
{
    &spawn<child_1>,
    &spawn<child_2>
};
```

Working example :

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class base
{
    public:
        virtual ~base () = default;

    public:
        virtual int f () const = 0;
};

class child_1 : public base
{
    public:
        int f () const override { return 1; }
};

class child_2 : public base
{
    public:
        int f () const override { return 2; }
};

template<typename T>
base * spawn ()
{
    return new T();
}

int main ()
{
    // With a vector
    std::vector<base *(*)()> vec_spawner =
    {
        &spawn<child_1>,
        &spawn<child_2>
    };

    base * child = vec_spawner[0]();
    // Do something with child here ...
    delete child;

    // With a map
    std::map<int, base *(*)()> map_spawner =
    {
        { 0, &spawn<child_1> },
        { 1, &spawn<child_2> }
    };

    child = map_spawner[1]();
    // Do something with child here ...
    delete child;
}
```

Now you can use user input to spawn a specific instance.

---

If your derived type constructors don't share the same parameters, unfortunately to my knowledge you can't use any container ... The only close possibility I can think of is this (working example):

```
#include <utility>

class base
{
    public:
        virtual ~base () = default;

    public:
        virtual int f () const = 0;
};

class child_1 : public base
{
    public:
        int f () const override { return 1; }
};

class child_2 : public base
{
    public:
        child_2 (int i) { (void) i; }

    public:
        int f () const override { return 2; }
};

template<typename... Args>
base * spawn (int input, Args && ... args)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case 0: return new child_1 {};
        case 1: return new child_2 { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
        // ...
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main ()
{
    int input = 1;
    base * child = spawn(input, 42);
    // Do something with child here ...
    delete child;
}
```

Comment: Some of the derived classes has parameterized constructor. How to define a template for that?

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution for your case if your project is a windows dll:

Define a factory method per derived class in your project.
the factory method to create `Class1` object should be named `us1` (or what ever is your user input to trigger this object creation).

Then use `GetProcAddress` API to obtain an address to the factory method based on its name (again the name is the user input) - and when obtained, simply invoke it to create an object.

Some code snippets to show the concept (it is very hard to suggest something real as you haven't posted your code)

```
class Base
{
public:
   void foo() = 0;
}
class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
   void foo() {};  
}

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
   void foo() {};  
}


extern "C"
{
    void __declspec(dllexport) us1 (Base*& pObj)
    {
       pObj = new Derived1();
    }
    void __declspec(dllexport) us2 (Base*& pObj)
    {
       pObj = new Derived2();
    }
}
```

then on your cpp file use something like

```
typedef void (__cdecl FUNCPROC)(Base*&);

string userInput;
cin >> userInput;

// get a handle to your dll memory (if this is a dll)

// assuming moduleHandle points to your dll memory

FUNCPROC* pProcAddr = GetProcAddress((HMODULE)moduleHandle, userInput);
```

Now `pProcAddr` is a pointer to the respected factory method based on your user input.

And getting the correct object

```
Base* pTmp = NULL;
pProcAddr(pTmp);
```

Now my above proposal is not complete and there are more things to handle (checking valid user input, checking the factory method exist in memory, etc...) but it should give you a general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code in many situations like yours.

Suppose all your class `Class1` ~ `ClassN` is derived from one abstract base class, `class Base`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

std::vector<std::function<std::shared_ptr<Base> ()>> CtorList = {
    [] { return std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Class1); },
    [] { return std::shared_ptr<Base>(new Class2); },
    [] { return std::shared_ptr<Base>(new ClassN); },
};

// Create
std::shared_ptr<Base> p = CtorList[num - 1]();
```

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/dz6JMk)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a map that maps from the input type to an factory object.  The factory object has a virtual method that returns the desired type.  Thus each class (Class1...ClassN) has a matching factory class (FCi) that knows how to construct an object of (Classi).

```
typedef std::map< Input, Factory > FactoryMap;

FactoryMap factoryMap;

void initFactoryMap()
{
       factoryMap[ Input1 ] = new FactoryForClass1();  // subclass of Factory, implementing constructClass
       factoryMap[ Input2 ] = new FactoryForClass2();
       factoryMap[ Input3 ] = new FactoryForClass3();
       ...
}

AbstractClass *inputHandler( Input n )
{
    return factoryMap[n]->constructClass( n ); // may not need to pass n in
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I really have to appreciate the effort you have defined so many classes...but i'would prefer to define a single class with a function which will be responsible for creating required table i'll try to figure out some logical way to create/print the table if the tables are kind of similar...or in the worst case i would use `switch` statement to choose which table to create/print.